# dynamic programming optimizaton,convex hull

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, convex-hull

There is a problem asked in contest. I already solved this problem with dynamic programming and its complexity `O(n^2)`.But i am looking more efficient way. I already saw that dynamic Programming can be optimized with convex hull. Do you have any suggestions. Thanks in advice.

Comment: This has nothing to do with convex hull. I don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: @izomorphius actually there is relationship with convex hull.The hint given with the question says that.

Comment: Did you probably forget to put a link in? its not at all clear what you are talking about.

Comment: @Henry actually there was a link but the problem linked had nothing to do with convex hull in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably referring to the convex hull trick for dynamic programming:
http://wcipeg.com/wiki/Convex_hull_trick

Answer (score 0):

Several algorithms with different complexity are listed in [convex hull algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms).